# HTML/CSS image and text formatting problems (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, formatting

The formatting on [this](http://zarwanhashem.com/projects) page is messing up.

1. The page formatting completely messes up when on mobile (The other pages work fine).
2. The images don't have equal spacing between them.
3. There's a random gap between the title "Projects" and the sentence below it.

Also: How do I add some white space at the bottom of the page below the last picture? I tried using `<br>` and an empty `<p>` tags but it doesn't work (though it might not work because of something I did that caused the issues above).

All of the code is public. You can access the CSS with `zarwanhashem.com/style.css`.

Comment: I cant help you now but try to solve it yourself with the inspector. i dont usually aks questions but take hand of the docs and some general questions, appart from the inspector

Comment: @wonderwhy what's the inspector? I've never head of it. And idk what docs you're talking about.

Comment: Boostrap documentation. And the inspector is a tool web browsers have to see the source code, dom tree, css properties and much more

Answer (score 1):

For the "random gap":

```
p {
  padding-top: 0;
}
```

Spacing between the images looks fine to me, and for white space on the bottom of the page:

```
body {
  padding-bottom: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. And the different projects are supposed to be listed beneath each other, not with that weird staircase effect. Unless you guys think that looks better? Lol.

Comment: This is not  all. You have to use bootstrap componets. Otherwise, why do you implement so? @user3641545

Comment: @wonderwhy What are you replying to? What's not all? The problems he posted a solution for worked. And I implemented bootstrap because it looks clean + does the mobile work for you. I don't know about most of the components, and there isn't a lot of good documentation + tutorials on the newest version. Everything seems to be about the old bootstrap.

Comment: @user3641545 If you could rate the answer up it would be nice.

Comment: @user3641545 the documentation is clear, but you have to be experienced with it. If you use bootstrap for it thats fine but you could take more advantage if you read the docs.

Answer (score 1):

So I think your issue for #1 is that you're not making use of any of the Bootstrap column classes. You'd want each project to be in its own `<div class="row"></div>`. Then assuming you want each project to be full width on larger screens you'd use `<div class="col-md-12"></div>`. If you then want each project to be less than fullscreen on mobile (here I'll use half) you would expand that to make it `<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-12"></div>`.

Then for #2, up top: `p {padding-top: 0;}` and down at the bottom: `body {padding-bottom: XXpx;}`

Comment: I looked up rows and span, but it doesn't seem to be working. If you check the page again you'll see my changes. What I'm trying to do is have the image with the description to the left of it, stack the projects on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to whats been posted, if you are adding custom margins to bootstrap, best wrap them in media queries only as your margins are to large for mobile. Avoid inline-styles to if want responsive.

Comment: I don't know what a media query is, or what an inline style is. I'm not very experienced with html and css.

Comment: inline style is when you add the style directly to the element <p style="margin:10px">. Media Queries allow you to apply css based on the size of the device viewing your content. To add a 10px bottom margin to all paragraphs when viewed at 640px or less you would add this to your css. @media only screen and (max-width: 40em) {
p {margin-bottom:10px}
}

Comment: @user3641545 come on!! Before start developing your web and say in your resume you are experienced with web development when you have no idea you must learn css and html.

Comment: Thanks Tristan Wood. @wonderwhy, I said I was "familiar" with CSS and HTML, not experienced. I'm not looking to go into web dev, I just want a simple online profile. I believe in learning on the job.